# Trying to test a simulate change on a textinput component using Jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, components, enzyme

I'm trying to simulate a change event on a component(ListPage)

```
 <TextInput
        className="search-s"
        id="textM"
        width="m"
        type="search"
        handleChange={this.props.updateS}
        placeholder="Search for a scenario"
      />
    </div>
```

The handleChange attribute calls a prop function called updateS which looks like

```
 updateS(e) {
     this.setState({
      name: e.target.value,
    }); 
  }
```

And what I currently have for the test function

```
 it("should call handleChange on change with the correct params", () => {
   const wrapper = shallow(<ListPage />);
   const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), "handleChange");
   wrapper.instance().forceUpdate();

   const p = wrapper.find(".search-s");
   p.simulate("change");
   expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
```

For some reason my test function doesnt work when I try to simulate a change and check whether the updateSearch function was called. All the guides online have examples of testing functions within the component but not passed props which I feel is what is causing the problem. Any insight would be great

Comment: Your component `ListPage` is rendering the `TextInput`? Where is the prop `updateS` located?

Comment: It's located in a state component which is the parent of the ListPage component

Comment: Then, you should be passing a `updateS` prop to `ListPage` when rendering it with `shallow`, shouldn't you?